# Python execution

Tags: python, runlevel

Is it possible for a python script to execute at a low run level?

Edit: 
To clarify, is it possible for a python script to run in the background, kind of like a daemon.

Comment: as Le Chiffre said in Casino Royale: Why not?

Comment: "low runlevel"?  You mean using `nice`?  As in `nice python myscript.py`?  Is that what you're asking?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: `man nice` --> "nice -- execute a utility with an altered scheduling priority"

Comment: I believe he is talking about the sysv init runlevels. I can however not think of a reason why Python wouldn't work in single user mode (runlevel 1).

Answer (score 5):

I put this file `nice.py` in my site-packages directory (on Windows):

```
import win32api,win32process,win32con
pid = win32api.GetCurrentProcessId()
handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, True, pid)
win32process.SetPriorityClass(handle, win32process.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)
```

Then I just `import nice` on any script I want to run at reduced priority.

Comment: +1 whether it answers the question or not (whatever the question actually was.. who knows?).  This could be quite useful along with `multiprocessing` to spawn off a secondary process that can do background work with minimal impact on the main process for a high-responsiveness application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The scripts that control daemons are (normally) plain old bash scripts and can run whatever a bash script can run. The only difference is that in a low runlevel, lots of other system services will not be running, so if the program tries to do something that depends on another daemon, that may fail.